# No able to install Jest on my computer, getting gyp errros

Tags: node.js, npm, jestjs

I am trying to install Jest on my computer with `npm install --save dev @types/jest`

I am getting the next errors:

```
npm install --save dev @types/jest
npm notice 
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 9.5.0 -> 9.6.0
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.6.0
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@9.6.0 to update!
npm notice 
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/rodolfo/sonatype/jars/node_modules/inotify
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! make: Entering directory '/home/rodolfo/sonatype/jars/node_modules/inotify/build'
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/inotify/src/bindings.o
npm ERR! make: Leaving directory '/home/rodolfo/sonatype/jars/node_modules/inotify/build'
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@19.7.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.2 found at "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/python@3.11/bin/python3.11"
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v19.7.0/node-v19.7.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v19.7.0/node-v19.7.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v19.7.0/SHASUMS256.txt
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v19.7.0/SHASUMS256.txt
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/python@3.11/bin/python3.11
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/rodolfo/sonatype/jars/node_modules/inotify/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/rodolfo/sonatype/jars/node_modules/inotify',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
npm ERR! ../src/bindings.h:10:48: error: ‘Handle’ has not been declared
npm ERR!    10 |                         static void Initialize(Handle<Object> target);
npm ERR!       |                                                ^~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/bindings.h:10:54: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
npm ERR!    10 |                         static void Initialize(Handle<Object> target);
npm ERR!       |                                                      ^
npm ERR! ../src/bindings.cc:11:14: error: variable or field ‘Initialize’ declared void
npm ERR!    11 |         void Inotify::Initialize(Handle<Object> exports) {
npm ERR!       |              ^~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/bindings.cc:11:34: error: ‘Handle’ was not declared in this scope
npm ERR!    11 |         void Inotify::Initialize(Handle<Object> exports) {
npm ERR!       |                                  ^~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/bindings.cc:11:47: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
npm ERR!    11 |         void Inotify::Initialize(Handle<Object> exports) {
npm ERR!       |                                               ^
npm ERR! ../src/bindings.cc:11:49: error: ‘exports’ was not declared in this scope
npm ERR!    11 |         void Inotify::Initialize(Handle<Object> exports) {
npm ERR!       |                                                 ^~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/bindings.cc: In static member function ‘static Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE NodeInotify::Inotify::AddWatch(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
npm ERR! ../src/bindings.cc:146:56: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::ToObject()’
npm ERR!   146 |                 Local<Object> args_ = info[0]->ToObject();
npm ERR!       |                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
npm ERR! In file included from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-primitive.h:11,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:11,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-array-buffer.h:13,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8.h:24,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/node.h:73,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/node_inotify.h:5,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/bindings.h:4,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-value.h:372:44: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const’
npm ERR!   372 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Object> ToObject(
npm ERR!       |                                            ^~~~~~~~
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-value.h:372:44: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
npm ERR! ../src/bindings.cc:149:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Has(v8::Local<v8::String>&)’
npm ERR!   149 |                 if (!args_->Has(path_sym)) {
npm ERR!       |                      ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-array-buffer.h:13,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8.h:24,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/node.h:73,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/node_inotify.h:5,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/bindings.h:4,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:325:37: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Has(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
npm ERR!   325 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Has(Local<Context> context,
npm ERR!       |                                     ^~~
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:325:37: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:331:37: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Has(v8::Local<v8::Context>, uint32_t)’
npm ERR!   331 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Has(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index);
npm ERR!       |                                     ^~~
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:331:37: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
npm ERR! ../src/bindings.cc:154:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Has(v8::Local<v8::String>&)’
npm ERR!   154 |                 if (!args_->Has(callback_sym) ||
npm ERR!       |                      ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-array-buffer.h:13,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8.h:24,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/node.h:73,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/node_inotify.h:5,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/bindings.h:4,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:325:37: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Has(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
npm ERR!   325 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Has(Local<Context> context,
npm ERR!       |                                     ^~~
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:325:37: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:331:37: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Has(v8::Local<v8::Context>, uint32_t)’
npm ERR!   331 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Has(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index);
npm ERR!       |                                     ^~~
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:331:37: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
npm ERR! ../src/bindings.cc:155:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::String>&)’
npm ERR!   155 |                         !args_->Get(callback_sym)->IsFunction()) {
npm ERR!       |                          ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-array-buffer.h:13,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8.h:24,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/node.h:73,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/node_inotify.h:5,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/bindings.h:4,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:290:43: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
npm ERR!   290 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
npm ERR!       |                                           ^~~
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:290:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:293:43: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Context>, uint32_t)’
npm ERR!   293 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
npm ERR!       |                                           ^~~
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:293:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
npm ERR! ../src/bindings.cc:160:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Has(v8::Local<v8::String>&)’
npm ERR!   160 |                 if (!args_->Has(watch_for_sym)) {
npm ERR!       |                      ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-array-buffer.h:13,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8.h:24,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/node.h:73,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/node_inotify.h:5,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/bindings.h:4,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:325:37: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Has(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
npm ERR!   325 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Has(Local<Context> context,
npm ERR!       |                                     ^~~
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:325:37: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:331:37: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Has(v8::Local<v8::Context>, uint32_t)’
npm ERR!   331 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Has(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index);
npm ERR!       |                                     ^~~
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:331:37: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
npm ERR! ../src/bindings.cc:163:40: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::String>&)’
npm ERR!   163 |                         if (!args_->Get(watch_for_sym)->IsInt32()) {
npm ERR!       |                              ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-array-buffer.h:13,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8.h:24,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/node.h:73,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/node_inotify.h:5,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/bindings.h:4,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:290:43: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
npm ERR!   290 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
npm ERR!       |                                           ^~~
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:290:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:293:43: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Context>, uint32_t)’
npm ERR!   293 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
npm ERR!       |                                           ^~~
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:293:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
npm ERR! ../src/bindings.cc:166:43: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::String>&)’
npm ERR!   166 |                         mask |= args_->Get(watch_for_sym)->Int32Value();
npm ERR!       |                                 ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-array-buffer.h:13,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8.h:24,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/node.h:73,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/node_inotify.h:5,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/bindings.h:4,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:290:43: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
npm ERR!   290 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
npm ERR!       |                                           ^~~
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:290:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:293:43: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Context>, uint32_t)’
npm ERR!   293 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
npm ERR!       |                                           ^~~
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:293:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
npm ERR! ../src/bindings.cc:172:50: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::String>&)’
npm ERR!   172 |                 String::Utf8Value path(args_->Get(path_sym));
npm ERR!       |                                        ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-array-buffer.h:13,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8.h:24,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/node.h:73,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/node_inotify.h:5,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/bindings.h:4,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:290:43: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
npm ERR!   290 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
npm ERR!       |                                           ^~~
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:290:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:293:43: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Context>, uint32_t)’
npm ERR!   293 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
npm ERR!       |                                           ^~~
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:293:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
npm ERR! ../src/bindings.cc:182:62: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::String>&)’
npm ERR!   182 |                 inotify->handle()->Set(descriptor, args_->Get(callback_sym));
npm ERR!       |                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-array-buffer.h:13,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8.h:24,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/node.h:73,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/node_inotify.h:5,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/bindings.h:4,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:290:43: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
npm ERR!   290 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
npm ERR!       |                                           ^~~
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:290:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:293:43: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Context>, uint32_t)’
npm ERR!   293 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
npm ERR!       |                                           ^~~
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:293:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
npm ERR! ../src/bindings.cc: In static member function ‘static Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE NodeInotify::Inotify::RemoveWatch(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
npm ERR! ../src/bindings.cc:195:44: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::Int32Value()’
npm ERR!   195 |                 watch = info[0]->Int32Value();
npm ERR!       |                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
npm ERR! In file included from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-primitive.h:11,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:11,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-array-buffer.h:13,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8.h:24,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/node.h:73,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/node_inotify.h:5,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/bindings.h:4,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-value.h:419:40: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<int> v8::Value::Int32Value(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const’
npm ERR!   419 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<int32_t> Int32Value(Local<Context> context) const;
npm ERR!       |                                        ^~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-value.h:419:40: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
npm ERR! ../src/bindings.cc: In static member function ‘static void NodeInotify::Inotify::Callback(uv_poll_t*, int, int)’:
npm ERR! ../src/bindings.cc:262:41: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::String>, Nan::imp::IntegerFactory<v8::Integer>::return_t)’
npm ERR!   262 |                                 obj->Set(Nan::New<String>("watch").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<Integer>(event->wd));
npm ERR!       |                                 ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-array-buffer.h:13,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8.h:24,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/node.h:73,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/node_inotify.h:5,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/bindings.h:4,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:244:37: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
npm ERR!   244 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
npm ERR!       |                                     ^~~
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:244:37: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:247:37: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::Context>, uint32_t, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
npm ERR!   247 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
npm ERR!       |                                     ^~~
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:247:37: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
npm ERR! ../src/bindings.cc:263:41: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::String>, Nan::imp::IntegerFactory<v8::Integer>::return_t)’
npm ERR!   263 |                                 obj->Set(Nan::New<String>("mask").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<Integer>(event->mask));
npm ERR!       |                                 ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-array-buffer.h:13,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8.h:24,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/node.h:73,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/node_inotify.h:5,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/bindings.h:4,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:244:37: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
npm ERR!   244 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
npm ERR!       |                                     ^~~
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:244:37: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:247:37: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::Context>, uint32_t, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
npm ERR!   247 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
npm ERR!       |                                     ^~~
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:247:37: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
npm ERR! ../src/bindings.cc:264:41: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::String>, Nan::imp::IntegerFactory<v8::Integer>::return_t)’
npm ERR!   264 |                                 obj->Set(Nan::New<String>("cookie").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<Integer>(event->cookie));
npm ERR!       |                                 ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-array-buffer.h:13,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8.h:24,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/node.h:73,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/node_inotify.h:5,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/bindings.h:4,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:244:37: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
npm ERR!   244 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
npm ERR!       |                                     ^~~
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:244:37: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:247:37: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::Context>, uint32_t, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
npm ERR!   247 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
npm ERR!       |                                     ^~~
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:247:37: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
npm ERR! ../src/bindings.cc:267:49: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::String>, v8::Local<v8::String>)’
npm ERR!   267 |                                         obj->Set(Nan::New<String>("name").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<String>(event->name).ToLocalChecked());
npm ERR!       |                                         ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-array-buffer.h:13,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8.h:24,
npm ERR!                  from /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/node.h:73,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/node_inotify.h:5,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/bindings.h:4,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:244:37: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
npm ERR!   244 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
npm ERR!       |                                     ^~~
npm ERR! /home/rodolfo/.cache/node-gyp/19.7.0/include/node/v8-object.h:244:37: note:
```

Not sure what is the cause of this errors, I upgrade my node and npm versions to:
npm -> 9.5
node -> 19.7.0

Any ideas what I am missing?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the command you are running is wrong.

The right command should be:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/jest
```